# How do I display a web page with Python?

Tags: python, html, pexpect, html-parsing

I want to read user input in Python to get a url (e.g. http://www.google.com) and then print the web page in HTML formatting (text only) to the terminal. I tried using `pexpect.spawn('elinks')` but elinks doesn't seem to write to stdout. I also looked at the HTMLParser module, but I don't know how I format the resulting text into something resembling a webpage. Any advice?

Comment: Your question is interesting if poorly phrased.  I believe you are asking "Is there a Python library that will render an HTML page in ASCII?"  I believe the correct answer to that question is, "Sorry, No."  Perhaps there is some small subset of tags (H*, DIV, P, BR) that you could look for and ignore the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is no small challenge.  The fact that you want to spawn `elinks` makes me wonder why you don't just use it instead.  See what extensibility/plugin/addon options it has, or try rewriting it to suit your specific needs.

Ultimately, you'll need to write your own browser layout engine with a curses backend.  If you're using python, `urwid` is a popular choice for curses layouts.

Comment: I am using Python because I need to display it as text in PyGame. Elinks will print to a terminal but I can't access the output from my application.

Comment: Well, I guess you're right. I'll try and write my own browser then.

Answer (score 0):

with python urllib

enter the url --> urllib --> the page --> print in console

```
# example in the python urllib page

import urllib

opener = urllib.FancyURLopener({})
f = opener.open("http://www.python.org/")
f.read()

# modify:

html = f.read()

# add:

print html

# to print in terminal
```

its similar to "curl" in unix

Comment: This just prints the raw HTML data, not formatted in any way.

Comment: ohh! I misunderstood your question... (then print the web page in HTML formatting (text only) to the terminal.) I understood in HTML formatting (html tags)

Answer (score -3):

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://www.google.com/')
print(r.content)
```